# How to run script 24/7 on Thonny IDE on a raspberry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, thonny

I’m kind of new to programming so sorry if this sounds like a dumb question. I would like to know whether or not I can run a script 24/7 in the thonny ide. The script basically just collects data from a website and prints it.

Comment: Let’s look at it differently: Why wouldn’t you be able to?

Comment: @AMC idk, I feel like the shell thing would just fill up with my data and just stop working or something

Comment: How often is the data collected, and how much is there on average?

Comment: The data is collected/printed every 8 seconds

Comment: And basically there’s a ton/endless amounts of data to collect

Comment: You’re collecting an infinite amount of data?

Comment: It’s not really infinite lmao. The code uses selenium and the chrome web driver to go to an Instagram tag “https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/“tag name”/?hl=en”. After that it goes through every single post and it collects/prints the amount of likes that post has. The tags that I typically choose have around 5-10 million posts

Comment: Current Thonny version automatically discards old output ´in the Shell once it grows too long. See Tools => Options => Shell.

Comment: Ohhhh coool because I was wondering why my code kept going. I thought that the shell would eventually fill up and overload the ram or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thonny is just an IDE, you dont need it for "production" runs. You should make it executable then run it with nohup. Check out this post for more details!
https://askubuntu.com/questions/396654/how-to-run-a-python-program-in-the-background-even-after-closing-the-terminal
(Check the top answer)

Comment: Ohhhh, I never thought of doing that. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Your welcome! Could you please accept the answer so that others can find it? @zack